# Remix: Potentially should be constant but is not.

Tags: remix

I am trying to execute a contract provided as a tutorial for Remix at the following link:
https://gangachris.com/posts/a-look-into-remix-ide/
The contract is:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Cars{
   struct Car{
      bytes32 make;
      unint year;
   }

   mapping(address => Car[]) public carOwners;

   function registerCar(bytes32 _make, uint r) public {
      carOwners[msg.sender].push(Car({ make: _make,
                                       year: yr}));
   }
   function changeOwnership(address toOwner, uint index) public returns (bool){
      if(carOwners[msg.sender].length == 0) {
         return false;
      }
      if(carOwners[msg.sender].length > index + 1) {
         return false;
      }
      carOwners[toOwner].push(carOwners[msg.sender][index]);
    }
    function getCarMake(address owner, uint index) public view returns (bytes32 carMake) {
       if(carOwners[owner].length == 0) {
          return;
       }
       if(carOwners[owner].length > index + 1){
          return;
       }
       carMake = carOwners[owner][index].make;
     }
}
```

I found by search that it’s a Remix problem and not associated with Solidity. Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: what is the error you get? how do you try to access it? what function are you calling?

Comment: After fixing two obvious typos with your code ("unint" and "r" variable) it compiles just fine in Remix.

Comment: This code doesn't compile because of a couple typos. Once those are fixed, the static analysis warning you mentioned does appear. It's safe to ignore, but I'm not sure why it appears. (Those functions _cannot_ be marked `constant`/`view`.)

Comment: Perhaps the Solidity compiler's understanding of `push` is poor? If you're interested in doing so, I would recommend filing an issue in the Solidity repo on GitHub.

Comment: Correction: the static analysis seems to come directly from Remix (https://github.com/ethereum/remix/blob/8bee42d9f99fd1fd7e8863e08fcc3a0659ebec6b/remix-analyzer/src/solidity-analyzer/modules/constantFunctions.js#L54). If you're interested, file an issue there.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for typos. I would log this issue in Remix as soon as possible.